# Trying to convert a column of integers into date, using parse function in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, date, format

Really new to Python, so this might be a really stupid question. I am trying to read in a dataframe and convert a column of integers into dates. The numbers are like this: 200205,200206,... in the format YYYYMM.

`parse_dates` works when a similar column is just integers defining years (2005,2006,...). But when the data introduces months, it's having issues.

This is what I have tried so far:

#### Read in returns data and clean up some columns, drop duplicates

```
returns_path = path + "DE_data_long.csv"
returns_df = pd.read_csv(returns_path, parse_dates=['mdate'], sep=';')
```

For reference, this piece of code did do what I wanted:

```
ratio_path = path + "DE_data_annual_long.csv"
ratios_df = pd.read_csv(ratio_path, parse_dates=['fyear'], sep=';')
ratios_df['year'] = ratios_df['fyear'].dt.year
ratios_df['month'] = ratios_df['fyear'].dt.month
ratios_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ISIN','month','year'], keep='first', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_parser` arg of `read_csv` method to read your date formats.

`parser = lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m')`

like `pd.read_csv(path, date_parser=parser)`